# pointer on pointer differences netbeans gdb debugger and gcc

Tags: c, linux, netbeans

My question ist

```
void function (const char **params)     
{
    const char *para;       
    para = &params[0]; //1
    para = params;     //2
    para = *&params;   //3 
}
```

all 3 options will be compiled by Netbeans gdb but gcc says sth like assignment from incompatible pointer type.

Why is this differnce .... got gcc 4.6.1 and what can I do in gcc to point to the value of **params with *para

Comment: unfortunately not... netbeans error and gcc params is used, but not defined error

Comment: char *para = params[0]; works with gcc/llvm

Comment: thx did it like u but with const char *para ... it worked then

Comment: yeah, I didn't write "const" for para nor params while testing it, so lazy. Glad it works

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In all three cases, the type of the right-hand side is `const char **`, which cannot be assigned to a `const char *` without a cast.

All compilers should warn you about this if you turn their warning level up high enough.

It's not clear what you want to do; if you want to point at the beginning of the first sub-array, then this would work:

```
para = params[0];
```

Comment: thanks.... this also worked without cast                          const char *para;
para = params[0];                                                    just ... tell me how would u do the cast (char*)? .....